MSBuild conditions: detect whether project file is built as project reference or standalone executable
I'm dealing with the NETSDK1152: Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path error while building a rather complex project. My project A depends on some classes in project B, both are to be compiled as executables, with their own appsettings.json. It's not an option to rename things, and I don't have time to make big refactorings.
I have followed every guide and solution I have been able to scrounge up, and I have spent about two hours reading the awful documentation for the MSBuild syntax, and no solution has presented itself, which is very frustrating.
What I need is to conditionally include the appsettings.json in project B only when project B is compiled as an executable.
How do I write that as a condition?
Something like
<ItemGroup Condition="$(we're compiling as an executable, here!)">
<Content Update="appsettings.json">
<CopyToOutputFirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
</ItemGroup>


ETA: I have found a workaround that involves using sed to delete parts of B.csproj during the docker build. I miss working with cargo.

An MSBuild project is not provided with the reason for why it is being built. You can't differentiate between a "build" and a "project reference build" and a project is expected to be built in the same manner regardless.
I can suggest three possible approaches.
Create Separate EXE and DLL Projects
Dynamically switching the type of assembly, i.e. EXE or DLL, that is produced by a project is counter to convention with .NET and MSBuild.
Split the existing B.csproj project into a Blib.csproj project which produces b.dll, and a Bapp.csproj project which produces b.exe. Move the classes that are common to A and B into Blib.csproj. Add project references to Blib to both A.csproj and Bapp.csproj.
Although the source files would be moved around between projects, there might be no or minimal code changes.
b.dll would need to be distributed with both a.exe and b.exe.
Create a Shared Project
You may not want to introduce a third assembly.
Instead, create a "Shared Project". A shared project is referenced as a project reference but there is no assembly. It is a set of source files that is injected into the referencing project.
Move the common classes to the shared project. Add references to the shared project to both A.csproj and B.csproj. Both A.csproj and B.csproj would produce EXEs.
(Despite the documentation link pointing to retired Xamarin content, shared projects are supported and are applicable to any .NET code.)
Create Custom Configurations
This last approach is unorthodox.
Projects have a Configuration and a Platform. The standard set of Configurations is Debug and Release. You can add additional configurations, e.g. DebugLib and ReleaseLib, and you can test the value of the $(Configuration) property.
In B.csproj when $(Configuration) is DebugLib or ReleaseLib:

Set the OutputType property to Library
Exclude the appsettings.json file

In A.csproj change the ProjectReference to B.csproj to add the SetConfiguration metadata. When the $(Configuration) in A.csproj is Release, set the SetConfiguration metadata for B.csproj to ReleaseLib. Debug should use DebugLib.

Fantastic with the last one. I don't have time for a major refactor, so that's a good option. I did intuit that this was counter to convention, but also that a better solution had to exist.
